# How to obtain private channel name from a forwarded message?

Tags: telegram, telethon

How to obtain a private channel name from a forwarded message? So the question is: if someone forwards a message from the private channel to the public channel\group or in DM, in the Telegram application you will see the name of this channel. But when you get this forwarded message by telethon you can get only channel ID. Using this ID is useless because on any request you will get `telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.ChannelPrivateError: The channel specified is private and you lack permission to access it. Another reason may be that you were banned from it (caused by GetBroadcastStatsRequest)`

Is it function missed in telethon or I just didn't find it? Thanks for any support.